# JPA With EclipseLink 2.3 Lazy Loading Weaving Method Not Found Exception

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, compile-time-weaving

We have a web application with JPA eclipselink 2.3.

We want to enable lazy loading, which requires us to enable weaving. The weaving process runs fine except that it cause a number of errors when we run our page.

The error is below:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 1.2.0.v20091016-r5565): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException Descriptor Exceptions: --------------------------------------------------------- 
Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 1.2.0.v20091016-r5565): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: 
The method [_persistence_setothrSrceOfSlsElmntLinkId_vh] or [_persistence_getothrSrceOfSlsElmntLinkId_vh] is not defined in the object [avon.maps.entities.SrceOfSlsElmnt]. 
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: avon.maps.entities.SrceOfSlsElmnt._persistence_getothrSrceOfSlsElmntLinkId_vh() Mapping: 
org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping[othrSrceOfSlsElmntLinkId] Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(avon.maps.entities.SrceOfSlsElmnt --> [DatabaseTable(SRCE_OF_SLS_ELMNT)]
```

Our persistence.xml includes the following line:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
```

Comment: Persistence includes the following line:

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

Comment: The error indicates weaving has not run fine, or hasn't run when it should have.  How have you configured weaving?  see http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/app_dev007.htm#CCHJEDFH for info.

Comment: Thanks Chris, it turns out I was weaving the classes correctly but not using the woven classes in my war file, duh! thanks for the help though!